# jQuery not working in a PHP include

Tags: php, jquery

I am building a website that utilizes a template and brings each "content" page in through an include statement.  On one page, I am using wt-rotator which is a jQuery script based slide show so to speak.  My problem is that the page that I am wanting to include runs the script perfectly, but when I try to view that page through the main template using the include, there is no slideshow.  This is the code that makes the "include" work:

```
<?
include  "/home/content/82/7960182/html/alliantwellness/contentfiles.php";

$pid = $_GET["pid"];

if  ($pid == "") {
    $pid = 0;
}

?>
```

That part is at the very top of the index.php page. Then this:

```
<? 
//Main Content including Navigation fills in here
    include  "/home/content/82/7960182/html/alliantwellness/content/" . $content[$pid]; 
?>
```

is what I use to call the page.  The contentfiles.php page is just an array of "content" pages that are stored in a folder called "content".

Any ideas on why the slideshow works outside the template, but not inside?

Here are the URL's so you can see what I am talking about:

http://www.alliantwellness.com
http://www.alliantwellness.com/content/home.php

Comment: Error console - *Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <*. This appears to be because `jquerry.wt-rotator.js` is an HTML document

Comment: not only is it HTML, but it tries to load itself. It also tries to load jQuery twice: version 1.3.2 from the CDN, and 1.7.1 from the local scripts folder.

Comment: Ok, I am not 100% sure what this means.  Sorry, I am very new to this and trying to crawl my way through it as I learn.  What would you suggest I do to remedy?

Comment: `.js` files are supposed to be just the Javascript code, not HTML documents with `<script>` tags.

Comment: I'm not sure why it is appearing that way.  There is no HTML within that jquerry.wt-rotator.js file.  I am just completely confused as to why it works perfectly outside of the include.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to remove this line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.alliantwellness.com/scripts/jquery.wt-rotator.js"></script>
```

from `index.html`. That file is not a Javascript file, it looks like it's a duplicate of the index.html file. You're already loading `jquery.wt-rotator.min.js` on a different line of the file, and that's the correct JS.

I also wonder why you're loading both http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js and http://www.alliantwellness.com/scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js, why do you need to load two different versions of jQuery from different locations? But `home.php` loads both of them and it seems to work.

Comment: Tried removing that line and also eliminating one of the versions of jQuery (tried it with each one by itself), no luck.  Still not working.  I can take this script and put it on the index page without using an include and it works like a charm.  But when I am trying to pull it through the include, it just won't work.